# Need to color star to the option of select

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, html-select

I need to have a select option with the red star at the end of all option.

```
<div class="styleSelect">
<select class="units">
 <option value="Metres">Metres*</option>
<option value="Feet">Feet*</option>
<option value="Fathoms">Fathoms*</option>
</select>
```

**Option has to be in black color and star need to be the red color.**

I have analyzed it. People recommended to add an image but that will not work on the browser other than firefox. Please help me on this.

Comment: it looks like dropdown options can have only one formatting. To get crossbrowser compatible solution, you will probably have to use radio selection.

Comment: in addition, most mobile browsers will open system prompt window, that has system formatting.

Comment: I'd suggest just putting the asterix outside the dropdown and to the right.

Answer (score 4):

```css
select.units option:after{
    content: '*';
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="styleSelect">
  <select multiple class="units" size="1">
    <option value="Metres">Metres</option>
    <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
    <option value="Fathoms">Fathoms</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we do it in the normal select box instead of select multiple?

Comment: I am afraid not. I want to do it in the normal select box but failed.

Comment: Anyways. Thx for ur help brother. This will help me to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select.units option {
    background-color: #000;
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Thx for responding. Brother, I don't want whole option to be in red. Metres has to be in black and star has to be in red.

Answer (score 0):

also try this.
i added class into option

```
<div class="styleSelect">
<select class="units">
    <option class="red" value="Metres">Metres*</option>
    <option value="Feet">Feet*</option>
    <option value="Fathoms">Fathoms*</option>
</select>
<style>
    select.units option{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000 ;
}
option.red {
    background-color: #000 !important;
    color: red !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I want red only for star, not for whole option.